# Storing polygon objects from a WPF application to database?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm currently working on a WPF-application (C#, using the Prism framework) that will contain a drawing pane where a user can draw polygons using his mouse.

But I'm wondering how I can make these drawings persistent.

I'm guessing that the best object to contain those drawings are the Polygon object?

I would also like to have those Polygons have certain attributes, such as a color etc. (if need be I can do this by defining my own Polygon-inherited object).

But I'm especially wondering how I can make this kind of information persistent in a database? (I'm using SQLite at the moment).

I want to be able to store Polygon information, including information such as the fill-color of that Polygon etc. in a database.

I've been googling this, but I'm not finding something useful. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't think there is a ready solution and tutorials for this problem lying around. You have to think about the database structure and what tables you need to create... Or use ORM

Answer (score 0):

You have to create model classes in order to store the necessary information, which you would like to store.

I think it might be the best solution to use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), so you wouldn't have to bother with creating the model classes, you could use the existing ones. But, in your case, it might saves a lot of unnecessary information into your tables.

---

If you are creating your own model classes, you can add a helper Extension Method to .net types, such as `Polygon`. That method would generate a storable model class from the .net class, which can be saved to database.

For example:
Model class:

```
public class PolygonDbFormat  // the class which contains the information you want to store
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Brush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

Defining the extension method:

```
public static class PolygonEx
{
    public static PolygonDbFormat AsDbFormat(this Polygon polygon)
    {
        return new PolygonDbFormat
        {
            Name = polygon.Name,
            Fill = polygon.Fill
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can save the `Polygon` class to the database this way:

```
var dbFormat = yourPolygon.AsDbFormat();
_yourDbManager.AddEntry(dbFormat); // your implementation to store the data in database
```